# React Native: Text wrapping inside View container with fixed-width button

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, word-wrap, react-native

I have a `View` container that displays a simple warning message. The message text should have line wrapping set on, the button should not.

They don't play along nicely and I can't get the text to wrap at the end of each line.

[image: Preview]

[image: Result]

[RNPlay (Link)](https://rnplay.org/apps/Ld-RUQ)

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red',flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between',alignItems:'center',flexWrap:'nowrap'}}>
  <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems:'center', marginLeft:15, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 18, fontWeight:'normal', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>You have deleted the item.</Text>
  </View>
  <TouchableHighlight style={{width:100,flexDirection:'column',marginVertical:15,flexWrap:'nowrap'}} >
    <View style={{right:0,width:100, flexDirection:'row', marginRight:15, paddingVertical:15, backgroundColor:'white',flexWrap:'nowrap'}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight:'bold', color:'red',flexWrap:'nowrap'}}>BACK</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is to use [`Dimensions`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) and to set main container' width.
Like:

```
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
let {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

and then in main component' style:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', ... , width}}>
```

Working here:
https://rnplay.org/apps/SampHw

Comment: But this text wrapping should also work inside other containers that differ in width from the main window, hope you understand me.

Comment: @PeterGerhat it should work, can you try and attach specific example?

Comment: Okay, looks like the problem was that I was creating the `<View>` as a variable inside `var msgBox = <View>...</View>;` and it didn't interpret the width correctly. Now it does work after putting the `<View>` directly into `return (<View>...</View>);`.